# How to implementing Android Studio login Activity with a class that extents an AsyncTask external db

Tags: android, android-layout

My app should check if an email and password pair exist in a remote db by a login.php.
I implemented Android Studio login Activity with an inner class that extents an AsyncTask with a login from as external page. The main part in outer class is this:

```
private BackgroundWorker  backgroundWork= null;
     private void attemptLogin() {
        if (backgroundWorker != null) {
            return;
        }
        mEmailView.setError(null);
        mPasswordView.setError(null);
        String email = mEmailView.getText().toString();
        String password = mPasswordView.getText().toString();

        boolean cancel = false;
        View focusView = null;
        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(password)) {
            mPasswordView.setError(getString(R.string.error_field_required));
            focusView = mPasswordView;
            cancel = true;
        } else if (!isPasswordValid(password)) {
            mPasswordView.setError(getString(R.string.error_invalid_email));
            focusView = mPasswordView;
            cancel = true;
        }
        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(email)) {
            mEmailView.setError(getString(R.string.error_field_required));
            focusView = mEmailView;
            cancel = true;
        } else if (!isEmailValid(email)) {
            mEmailView.setError(getString(R.string.error_invalid_email));
            focusView = mEmailView;
            cancel = true;
        }
        if (cancel) {
            focusView.requestFocus();
        } else {
            showProgress(true);
            String type = "login";
            BackgroundWorker  backgroundWorker = new BackgroundWorker(type, email, password);
            backgroundWorker.execute((Void) null);
        }
    }
```

And this the inner class that extends Asynctask:

```
    public class BackgroundWorker extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {
            private final String mEmail;
            private final String mPassword;
            private final String mtype;
           public BackgroundWorker(String type,String email, String pass) {
               mEmail=email;mtype=type;mPassword=pass;
            }
            @Override
            protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
                String login_url = "http://www.example.com/login.php";
// Returns a string of "1" if it is correct email and password
                 if (mtype.equals("login")) {
                    try {
                        URL url = new URL(login_url);
                        HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                        httpURLConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
                        httpURLConnection.setDoOutput(true);
                        httpURLConnection.setDoInput(true);
                        OutputStream outputStream = httpURLConnection.getOutputStream();
                        BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(outputStream, "UTF-8"));
                        String post_data = URLEncoder.encode("email", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(mEmail, "UTF-8") + "&"
                                + URLEncoder.encode("password", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(mPassword, "UTF-8");
                        bufferedWriter.write(post_data);
                        bufferedWriter.flush();
                        bufferedWriter.close();
                        outputStream.close();
                        InputStream inputStream = httpURLConnection.getInputStream();
                        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream, "iso-8859-1"));
                        String result = "";
                        String line = "";
                        while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                            result += line;
                        }
                        bufferedReader.close();
                        inputStream.close();
                        httpURLConnection.disconnect();
                        return result;
                    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
                return "0";
            }
            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
    //            backgroundWork = null;
                showProgress(false);
                if (result == "1") {
                    Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
                    startActivity(i);
                } else {
                    mPasswordView.setError(getString(R.string.error_incorrect_password));
                    mPasswordView.requestFocus();
                }
            }

            @Override
            protected void onCancelled() {
                showProgress(false);
            }
        }
```

> However I managed to implement it with a simple Login Activity and a separate public class in a different project successfully.

And the stack trace is this:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
   Process: dk.hydraulik, PID: 3894
   java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occurred while executing doInBackground()
   at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:309)
   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:354)
   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:223)
   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
   at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:234)
   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113)
   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)
   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
      Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: Permission denied (missing INTERNET permission?)
    at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:464)
    at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByNameImpl(InetAddress.java:252)
    at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:215)
    at com.android.okhttp.internal.Network$1.resolveInetAddresses(Network.java:29)
    at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.RouteSelector.resetNextInetSocketAddress(RouteSelector.java:188)
    at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.RouteSelector.nextProxy(RouteSelector.java:157)
     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.RouteSelector.next(RouteSelector.java:100)
     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.createNextConnection(HttpEngine.java:357)
     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.nextConnection(HttpEngine.java:340)
    at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:330)
    at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:248)
    at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:433)
    at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:114)
    at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getOutputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:245)
    at dk.hydraulik.LoginActivity$BackgroundWorker.doInBackground(LoginActivity.java:204)
    at dk.hydraulik.LoginActivity$BackgroundWorker.doInBackground(LoginActivity.java:187)
    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:295)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
    at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:234) 
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113) 
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588) 
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818) 
                       Caused by: android.system.GaiException: android_getaddrinfo failed: EAI_NODATA (No address associated
```

> Edit:I added the internet permission, and now the above error is  gone but it still is not working with the correct email and password.

Now gives this error:

```
$ adb shell am start -n "dk.hydraulik/dk.hydraulik.LoginActivity" -a android.intent.action.MAIN -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER
Connected to process 3640 on device emulator-5554
W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/app/dk.hydraulik-1/lib/x86_64
I/InstantRun: Instant Run Runtime started. Android package is dk.hydraulik, real application class is null.
W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/app/dk.hydraulik-1/lib/x86_64
W/art: Verification of android.support.v7.view.ActionMode android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.startSupportActionModeFromWindow(android.support.v7.view.ActionMode$Callback) took 205.213ms
D/OpenGLRenderer: Use EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED: true
I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
D/gralloc_ranchu: Emulator without host-side GPU emulation detected.
I/Choreographer: Skipped 64 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
W/IInputConnectionWrapper: getSelectedText on inactive InputConnection
I/Choreographer: Skipped 36 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
W/IInputConnectionWrapper: requestCursorAnchorInfo on inactive InputConnection
W/IInputConnectionWrapper: getTextBeforeCursor on inactive InputConnection
I/Choreographer: Skipped 55 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
W/IInputConnectionWrapper: getTextBeforeCursor on inactive InputConnection
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated and please do comment and answer this, and  I can change the external url content if need be.

Comment: Missing Internet permission..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should include internet permission

> Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: Permission denied (missing INTERNET permission?)

Edit your `AndroidManifest.xml` like this:

```
<manifest xlmns:android...>
...
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<application ...
</manifest>
```

Answer (score 1):

Check first whether network connection is available or not before calling Http request

```
    private boolean isNetWorkAvailable() {
    boolean haveConnectedWifi = false;
    boolean haveConnectedMobile = false;

    ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo[] netInfo = cm.getAllNetworkInfo();
    for (NetworkInfo ni : netInfo) {
        if (ni.getTypeName().equalsIgnoreCase("WIFI"))
            if (ni.isConnected())
                haveConnectedWifi = true;
        if (ni.getTypeName().equalsIgnoreCase("MOBILE"))
            if (ni.isConnected())
                haveConnectedMobile = true;
    }
    return haveConnectedWifi || haveConnectedMobile;
}
```

Use it as:

```
    if(isNetWorkAvailable()){
     BackgroundWorker  backgroundWorker = new BackgroundWorker(type, email, password);
     backgroundWorker.execute((Void) null);

   } else{
   //show a toast message that network not available
   }
```

You also need to set permission in manifest:

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```